# Eclipse android emulator freezes

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, emulation, adt

sorry if this is a dumb question. im very new to development.

When I run the emulator on android, instead of loading up a home screen. it just stays at this screen: 
[image: screenshot]

I don't get any error codes or anything, and it does NOT freeze my entire computer or eclipse, it just freezes the emulator and doesn't move on. I just have to press the (x) button to exit it. so I was wondering if anyone knows how to fix this and thanks !

### edit

I would also like to mention that after a really long time I get this screen [image: screenshot]

Comment: Is there any chance you can run your emulator via command line? Usually debug statements are printed out if you do it that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better option is to use [bluestacks android emulator](http://bluestacks.com/). In my opinion, it is much faster than Google Android emulator.

Here are steps for setup:

1 - Install bluestacks emulator

2 - Open cmd

3 - Type command: `set path="Android SDK\config\platform-tools"` (you need   to enter the full path  where is your **adb.exe** located

4 - `adb connect 127.0.0.1`

Now you should be able to run apps directly to BlueStack emulator from your IDE.

Comment: bluestack by default use port 10001. so `adb connect 127.0.0.1:10001`

Comment: bluestacks work with android < 3.0 so it is not suited for all applications.

Answer (score 2):

what I have found that helps me when a device goes offline is to go into the Window--->Show View --->Devices (you may have to click "Other" and select it there and then select "reset adb"

[image]

Sometimes the device goes "offline" for an unexplained (not explained to me anyway!) reason

You may just want to create another emulator with the same specs.  Did you try that?

P.S. you may have to restart it again to have it listed in your Devices window

Comment: I agree with him trying to make a new emulator, but what does the first part of your answer have to do with his problem? His emulator is just slow, not offline.

Comment: Resetting the adb resets the connection, it doesn't wipe data.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, ARM system images are very slow; Intel x86 images are faster, up to 4x; so you should try with an Intel image.  Trying with a smaller screen should also help; especially if your memory options are low.  With such a big screen as the one shown above, it's possible that your emulator is simply to low on memory.

Answer (score 0):

Get a x86 build from android-x86.org, install with virtualbox (or anything else, but virtualbox if free). 
Find the ip of your vm by ctrl+F1 (change to cli, ctrl+F7 to change back to graphical mode) and `netcfg`. Then `adb connect 192.168.1.5`(replace with your vm's ip).

then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem with the 4.2 SDK recently installed on desktop Ubuntu 12.xy and WinXP. I thought it odd because there was no problem with the 2.2 SDK I had played with on my notebook Ubuntu 10.xx system last year or so.  Following the suggestion of NH, I used the SDK manager to install 2.2 (API 8) and created an emulator for that level and that emulator runs as well on these desktop systems as on the notebook system. Since I'm just learning and my physical device is at 2.2, I'm going to leave it like this until such time as I need to move up.

Answer (score 0):

Wipe user data before launching the emulator. It will reset the emulator and all applications, but at least you don't need to recreate it or reconfigure it.

Make sure you uncheck this box the next time you launch the emulator.

[image: Wipe user data]

Answer (score -1):

Emulators are inherently slow, because it has to simulate all the hardware of your device (including camera, wifi adapter, etc.) in software.

That said, You should set aside half a day for the emulator to load for the first time (walk the dog or something while you are waiting), and then every time after that it should be faster.

Pick an API below 14 (such as API 10 Gingerbread, most devices run this) to improve the loading of the emulator.

Then after the emulator has had however long it needs to load, you can just click run in eclipse and your app should launch in the emulator.  When you are done, don't close the emulator, just go back to eclipse, make your edits to the code, and then hit run again and it will automatically close the app, replace it with the new version, and launch.

Comment: -1 Not sure how this addresses the OP's issue of letting it sit for a very long time only to be faced with _Unfortunately, Launcher has stopped_

Comment: That is the reason for picking an earlier API.  I've had better success that way.